# PowerDNS 3+ - Recursive queries for subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, powerdns

We are trying to find functionality in the  PDNS 3.x that existed in PDNS < 2.9.2.5. Whereby if we have a domain in the database backend with records, if a query is unable to resolve a subdomain it would then query the recursor setup in the pdns.conf file.

We have found that on Centos 6.x the rpm packages are the latest verison of pdns where by 5.x available was pdns-2.9.22-4.el5. The pdns-2.9.22-4.el5 package works as expected but when upgrading servers to Centos 6.x we loose this required functionality.

pdns-backend-mysql-2.9.22-4.el5.rpm fails to install on Centos 6.x due to mysql libs that aren't availble, this is caused by an upgrade in the mysql version whereby the pdns backend mysql requires older mysql libs then what is available on centos 6.x .

Installing from source is also troublesome with the following errors - http://pastebin.com/B5cUuD08

Answer (score 1):

The recursor forwarding behaviour in PowerDNS 3 has indeed changed, compared to 2.9.22. The behaviour you are looking for is not currently available. We recommend pointing your clients directly to a recursor. Sorry.